# Routing over VPN Uplink - Packets do not traverse tunnel

Tags: routing, vpn

I want to route between my home LAN and a remote LAN over a VPN tunnel between my home server and a remote server.
Here's the setup:

```
                       _________________                                   _____________                                    __________________
              ________|                 |______                  _________|             |________                __________|                  |
             |        |                 |      |                |         |             |        |              |          |                  |
Remote-LAN---| enp1s0 |  remote-server  | tun1 |---VPN-Tunnel---| uplink0 | home server | enp2s0 |---Home-LAN---| Ethernet | Windows Notebook |
             |________|                 |______|                |_________|             |________|              |__________|                  |
                      |_________________|                                 |_____________|                                  |__________________|
```

**Remote Server**

*Interfaces*

```
enp1s0: 192.168.178.10/24
tun1: 10.11.0.2/24
```

*Routes*

```
default via 192.168.178.1 dev enp1s0 proto static
10.11.0.0/24 dev tun1 proto kernel scope link src 10.11.0.2
172.23.56.0/24 via 10.11.0.1 dev tun1
192.168.178.0/24 dev enp1s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.178.10
```

*Routing is enabled*

```
# cat /etc/sysctl.d/30-ipforward.conf
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

*Firewall*

```
-A ufw-user-input -i tun1 -j ACCEPT
```

**home server**

*Interfaces*

```
enp2s0: 172.23.56.2/24
uplink0: 10.11.0.1/24
```

*Routes*

```
default via 172.23.56.254 dev enp2s0 proto static
10.11.0.0/24 dev uplink0 proto kernel scope link src 10.11.0.1
172.23.56.0/24 dev enp2s0 proto kernel scope link src 172.23.56.2
192.168.178.0/24 via 10.11.0.2 dev uplink0
```

*Routing enabled*

```
$ cat /etc/sysctl.d/routing.conf
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

*Firewall*

```
table inet filter {
        chain input {
                type filter hook input priority 0; policy accept;
                ct state { established, related } accept
                ct state invalid drop
                iifname "lo" accept
                ip protocol icmp accept
                ip6 nexthdr ipv6-icmp accept
                iifname "enp2s0" tcp dport ssh accept
                tcp dport { http, https } accept
                udp dport { openvpn, 1195 } accept
                iifname "game0" jump game-vpn
                reject
        }

        chain game-vpn {
                tcp dport 25565 accept
        }

        chain forward {
                type filter hook forward priority 0; policy accept;
                ip saddr 172.23.56.0/24 ip daddr 192.168.178.0/24 accept
                ip saddr 192.168.178.0/24 ip daddr 172.23.56.0/24 accept
                drop
        }

        chain output {
                type filter hook output priority 0; policy accept;
        }
}
```

**Notebook (Win 10)**

*Interface*

```
Ethernet: 172.23.56.20
```

*Route*

```
192.168.178.0    255.255.255.0      172.23.56.2     172.23.56.20     51
```

Unfortunately, when I ping from the notebook to the remote LAN

```
ping 192.168.178.10
```

I get timeouts.
The echo request seems to get forwarded and reaches the home server's VPN interface:

```
$ sudo tcpdump -i uplink0 "host 172.23.56.20"
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on uplink0, link-type RAW (Raw IP), capture size 262144 bytes
21:03:56.651706 IP gamebook.fritz.box > 192.168.178.10: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 265, length 40
21:04:01.284635 IP gamebook.fritz.box > 192.168.178.10: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 266, length 40
21:04:06.289546 IP gamebook.fritz.box > 192.168.178.10: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 267, length 40
```

But they don't reach the remote VPN interface:

```
tcpdump -i tun1 "host 172.23.56.20"
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on tun1, link-type RAW (Raw IP), capture size 262144 bytes
<a whole lotta nothing>
```

What am I missing? I don't want to use NAT, just plain old IPv4 routing.

Comment: At the "remote server", it seems that you only allow "INPUT" traffic. What about if you allow "FORWARD" traffic to?. Your routes and ip_forwarding seem to be fine, but if your default policy is DROP/REJECT, your Remote server box will not forward if firewall does not allow...

Comment: @nwildner Thanks, I will check that asap. But regardless of the forwarding, souldn't `tcpdump` nonetheless detect the packet on ingress?

Comment: Yup. Ingress should be logged since `tcpdump` in this case is processes before `iptables`. What if you try a `tcpdump -i tun1 -nevvv dst host 192.168.178.10` inside "remote-server" box just to double-check?